# Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured. Getting dis error while running app

Tags: java, spring

This is application properties code,please check and tell me how to fix the error.

```
    debug=true
    server.port=9090
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
#create, update, create-drop, validate
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
    #file related all configurations
    
    spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
    spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB
    
project.image=images/
    #here we are allowing debug so that we can get every log related to security on console
    logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
     #spring.profiles.active will tell us which profile we are using 
    spring.profiles.active= prod
```

This is application-developer properties code

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/blog_app_apis
spring.datasource.username = 
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

This is application-production properties code

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://blog-db.cx8gwdujroiq.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/blog_app_apis
spring.datasource.username = pankaj
spring.datasource.password=kicker12345



This is the error message:
```

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Action:

Consider the following:
If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (the profiles prod are currently active).

Comment: The error message is quite clear about the problem. Edit question to add your data source configuration and somebody might be able to help. Also, [don't upload images of errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question), paste the text in the question.

Comment: Please never post images of text. They are not searchable, we cannot copy-paste... Always copy-paste the text and format it properly.

Comment: @Chaosfire  I am unable to paste the code in the question, can you please check from the comments?

Comment: @Pankaj Of course you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73611139/edit) your own question.

Comment: @Chaosfire sir,I have edited the question please kindly check it

Comment: @g00se Sir,I have edited the question and written the codes,please kindly check it,

Comment: You should follow the Spring methods for adding a datasource to an *external* database. And change your credentials - anyone can connect *at the moment* to that database. You can drop the table called ```bemorecareful```

Answer (score 1):

Your production configuration is missing the database driver property, which you should clearly understand from the reason section in the exception message:

`Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class`

Since you have the application.properties file with the default configuration properties, you can use the fix suggested to you by the Spring framework:

`Consider the following: If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL, or Derby), please put it on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (the profiles prod are currently active).`

In order to fix the error for the production profile you need to add the following property to your application.properties file: `spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`

The resulting file should look like this:

```js
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true 
debug=true
server.port=9090
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
#create, update, create-drop, validate
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB
project.image=images/
#here we are allowing debug so that we can get every log related to security on console
logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
#spring.profiles.active will tell us which profile we are using
spring.profiles.active=prod
```

This will add the default database driver for all your profile. So be mindful to change this if some specific profile will use a database that differs from MySQL.

**Updated:**

You also have the incorrect name of the active profile. In your application.properties file you have a such line that sets the active profile of your application:

```js
spring.profiles.active=prod
```

But your profile-based file is called `application-production.properties`. The Spring framework has a such naming format for configuration properties files:

```js
application-[PROFILE_NAME].properties
```

So you should also rename your `application-production.properties` file to `application-prod.properties` to match the value from the `spring.profiles.active` property.

Comment: Sir, I have done as mentioned by you,but it is still giving the same error.

Comment: @Pankaj Please post your pom.xml or build.gradle file with dependencies and specify how you run your application and with which profile?

Comment: @Pankaj Please check the updated section in my answer. I have specified one more fix for your configuration file.